# C# Get key/name from JSON children

Tags: c#, json, loops, automapper, keyvaluepair

I am recieving this JSON response from an API:

```
{
  "type": "link",
  "title": "One or more validation errors occurred.",
  "status": 400,
  "traceId": "0000000000000",
  "errors": {
    "inputNumber": [
      "Must be 5 characters."
    ],
    "inputWord": [
      "Required."
    ]
  }
}
```

I am using a profile with AutoMapper to map the response to a model. Here is the code where I'm trying to map the JSON errors property to a `Dictionary<string, List<string>>` property in my response model:

```
     // Map for Errors property
     .AfterMap((src, dest) =>
     {
         dest.Errors = new Dictionary<string, List<string>>();
         var jsonErrorDict = src.SelectTokens("errors").Children();

         foreach (var token in jsonErrorDict)
         {
             // Not working right: Token contains both key and value
             var key = token;
             var value = new List<string>();

             if (token.HasValues)
             {
                 var jsonErrorKeyValues = token.Children();

                 foreach (JToken innerToken in jsonErrorKeyValues)
                 {
                     value.Add(innerToken.ToString());
                 }

                 dest.Errors.Add(key.ToString(), value);
             }
         }
```

But the token variable contains both the key ("inputNumber" for example) as well as the value ("Must be 5 characters"), so when the mapping is done it looks like this:

```
"errors": {
    "\"inputNumber\": [\r\n  \"Must be 5 characters.\"\r\n]": [
      "[\r\n  \"Must be 5 characters\"\r\n]"
    ],
   "\"inputWord\": [\r\n  \"Required\"\r\n]": [
      "[\r\n  \"Required.\"\r\n]"
  }
```

Im just testing it and getting the response from an escaped string so ignore the escape symbols like \r.

How do I get only the key name?

**EDIT:**
I added this to the key variable:

```
var key = token.ToString().Split(':');
```

And then when I'm adding it to the dest.Errors dictionary I do this:

```
dest.Errors.Add(key[0], value);
```

Doesn't feel like the best solution though so alternative solutions are more than welcome.

Comment: Are you not adding both key and value here - dest.Errors.Add(key.ToString(), value); and dest.Errors.keys wont work?

Comment: Yes, since dest.Errors is a dictionary I need to add both key and value, and I want the key to be "inputNumber" and value "Must be 5 characters". But right now I get both of them in the variable "key". I'm not sure I understand your second question?

Comment: `dest.Errors = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, List<string>>>(src.SelectTokens("errors"));`